# Fourier transform from the fourier series

Tags: fourier-transform

can someone help me understand where the 1/T  normalising factor goes when taking the limit of the Fourier series to turn into a Fourier transform.

There exists a derivation from Fourier series to transform but what they do in it is derive the inverse Fourier transform and they take the Fourier transform as the definition.

I cant find anyone showing the Fourier transform as a direct consequence of extending the periodicity to infinity and the "disappearance" of the normalising 1/T factor

Comment: The Fourier transform does not assume a periodic function, is integrated from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, and hence the $\frac{1}{T}$ factor associated with a Fourier series does not apply. The Fourier series coefficients are derived from an integral over the period $T$ which is related to the corresponding $\frac{1}{T}$ factor.

Comment: @StevenClark I am trying to understand where the coefficient went. Bcos the fourier transform is supposed to return me the amplitude of a frequency present in the original function. If the function was periodic the fourier series also provides with me with the same (except discrete). under the limit, wouldn't I be dividing by a period of infinity. Why does the FT not have any coefficient to divide it. How exactly are they different? Im thinking of them as nearly the same thing except one is a generalized operation. Is the amplitudes received from the FT a scaled version of the actual

Comment: I think it would be helpful to write out the specific expressions that you are referring to because there are different conventions that are used as far as the scale factor ( which in turns depends on whether one is using $2 \pi$ explicitly in the integrand ) so the answer might depend on that.